# Weird issue Ajax calls wrong aspx.cs file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a weird issue.

When I use Ajax to call a function in an aspx.cs file, the Ajax sends the request in the wrong aspx file even if I ask another file.
In fact, every time I try it call the aspx.cs file of the first page.

this is my ajax :

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "NewLayerPage.aspx/getData2",
        data: dataToSend,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(dataToSend);
            console.log("data sended");
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
```

When I use that code in a function,
it is looking for "getData2" in "FirstPage.aspx.cs" instead of "NewLayerPage.aspx.cs".
I'm sure my function in NewLayer work because when I copy/paste it in FirstPage I have no issue.
This is
[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnbUG.png) :

Any ideas ?
Thanks for all !

EDIT :
So when I comment the function in "firstPage" I got an error as you can see
 [here :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4nKY.png)

But if
[I do not comment the function I do not have an error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgC5q.png)

Comment: Your screenshot shows it's calling NewLayerPage and it's returning a 500 error.  500 error code means the call went through to NewLayerPage getData2 but the code in that method throw an error.  Might want to try to debug that method.

Comment: That is weird thing, is when getData2 is in FirstPage.aspx.cs I do not have a 500 error. And it's work perfectly.
I think it's because Ajax look for FirstPage instead of NewLayerPage but I don't know why...

Comment: As the first comment notes - looks 100% perfect normal to me. Your js code (ajax) I assume is in NewLaywerPage.aspx. and your screen shot shows that was the URL used. Seems perfect normal to me. Your url in the ajax call matches what the error message shows.

Comment: Hi ! I add pictures to help you understand mi issue.